# How to replace a variable with another variable in PERL?

Tags: regex, perl, search, replace, match

I am trying to replace all words from a text except some that I have in an array. Here's my code:

```
my $text = "This is a text!And that's some-more text,text!";
while ($text =~ m/([\w']+)/g) {

    next if $1 ~~ @ignore_words;

    my $search  = $1;
    my $replace = uc $search;
    $text =~ s/$search/$replace/e;
}
```

However, the program doesn't work. Basically I am trying to make all words uppercase but skip the ones in @ignore_words. I know it's a problem with the variables being used in the regular expression, but I can't figure the problem out.

Comment: Your script works if you make a copy of `$text` and do the replace on that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $text = "This is a text!And that's some-more text,text!";

my @ignorearr=qw(is some);

my %h1=map{$_ => 1}@ignorearr;
$text=~s/([\w']+)/($h1{$1})?$1:uc($1)/ge;

print $text;
```

On running this,

```
THIS is A TEXT!AND THAT'S some-MORE TEXT,TEXT!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can figure the problem out of your code if instead of applying an expression to the same control variable of a `while` loop, just let `s/../../eg` do it globally for you:

```
my $text = "This is a text!And that's some-more text,text!";

my @ignore_words = qw{ is more };

$text =~ s/([\w']+)/$1 ~~ @ignore_words ? $1 : uc($1)/eg;

print $text;
```

And on running:

```
THIS is A TEXT!AND THAT'S SOME-more TEXT,TEXT!
```